# mystery: chef-client/knife: they are ignoring any error in knife.rb and client.rb

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I happened find that in `~/.chef/knife.rb` or `/etc/chef/client.rb`,
any error will be ignored by knife or chef-client.

```
...
a_non_exist_method a_non_exist_var
...
puts "==== #{a_non_exist_method}"
```

it is totally fine, even if the `a_non_exist_method a_non_exist_var` is absolutely wrong.
The result will be of course

```
====
```

How does `chef-client`/`knife` execute `client.rb`/`knife.rb`?

PS: I know `knife.rb` and `client.rb` is a config file, not supposed to add user program logic there, just curious that why it put anything in it without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is evaluated as a Chef::Config class instance, which inherit from mixlib-config, which depending on how you tested that may not be in strict mode ([relevant code](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-config/blob/e9ea644be73d113458a75946a73d424bebe02b30/lib/mixlib/config.rb#L620))

So you may end up with a property ignored without warning nor error when not setting strict mode.

Your `puts` just get evaluated as standard ruby, string interpolation search for a variable even if you called it `a_non_exist_method` and from ruby duck typing, it's a nil value, wich interpolated as string is an empty string.

Comment: Drop on Chef community slack, there's a bit more activity. So answers tend to get old/irrelevant/wrong with time and I think most of those knowing the internals of Chef have left now.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I will try Chef community slack later.